# ImportError: cannot import name 'TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer' from 'itsdangerous'

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm running a flask app using itsdangerous python package in AWS EC2 instance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 4, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/home/ubuntu/RHS_US/application/portal/__init__.py", line 29, in create_app
    from portal.users.routes import users
  File "/home/ubuntu/RHS_US/application/portal/users/routes.py", line 7, in <module>
    from portal.models import User
  File "/home/ubuntu/RHS_US/application/portal/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
ImportError: cannot import name 'TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer' from 'itsdangerous' (/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/itsdangerous/__init__.py)
```

Any resolution for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First make sure to re-install and update itsdangerous.

```
pip install -U itsdangerous
```

Then what you want to do is

```
 from itsdangerous.url_safe import URLSafeTimedSerializer as Serializer
```

This works well.

Answer (score 17):

In the latest version of itsdangerous, TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer is no longer available. Try this instead. It worked for me. `from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer as Serializer`

Answer (score 6):

Itsdangerous is a very common and popular package used for serialization in other packages and apps.
To fix this:

1. Upgrade your Flask to the newest version  ---  `pip install flask –upgrade`
2. Downgrade itsdangerous to version 2.0.1   ---  `pip install itsdangerous==2.0.1`
3. After downgrading it, install email_validator again to make the issue fixed ---  `pip install email_validator`

I hope this fixes the issue for you. **Happy Coding**

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem, and I fixed it by following these steps:

First, I force-reinstalled the 'itsdangerous' library to version 2.0.1 using the following command:

> pip install --force-reinstall itsdangerous==2.0.1

After reinstalling, I imported the 'TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer' class from 'itsdangerous':

> from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer

Now, my code works perfectly, and I was able to generate and verify tokens without any issues.